# String.replacingOccurrences with large String memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, string, out-of-memory

In our app we generate a PDF file. So we use an HTML file as template and load this template to `String` then replace all *placeholders* with correct values:

```
let template = Bundle.main.path(forResource: “reportTemplate”, ofType: "html")
do {
    var htmlTemplate = try String(contentsOfFile: template!)
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replacingOccurrences(of: “#LOGO#”, with: logoBase64)
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replacingOccurrences(of: “#TITLE#”, with: “PDF FILE“)
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replacingOccurrences(of: “#IMAGE1#”, with: reportImageBase64)
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replacingOccurrences(of: “#IMAGE2#”, with: reportImageBase64)
    //…
} catch {
    print(“\(error)“)
}
```

The PDF may contain numbers of images thus the string grow bigger as we converting these images to Base64.

We then notice that this cause issue on memory as it goes high when we run the generation code. And we receive random crash reports due to ***NSMallocException*** pointing to this.

Any suggestion to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to mutate your `String` *in-place* as this might substantially reduce your memory usage. For instance:

```
let token = htmlTemplate.range(of: “#LOGO#”)!
htmlTemplate.replaceSubrange(token, with: logoBase64)
...
```

If a token might appear more than once — or not at all! — you need to account for that as well:

```
while let token = htmlTemplate.range(of: “#LOGO#”) {
    htmlTemplate.replaceSubrange(token, with: logoBase64)
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, We tried this and it seems that the time it takes to finish the process is longer than using the `replacingOccurrences`. We rewrite the code so it will generate first a "temporary html file" then use an "absolute path" of the images as the "src" so far this works fine and the memory usage is at normal level.